# OpenLayers 3.11.1 - Replace default attribution by an image

Tags: openlayers

I am looking for a way to replace the default attribution of my map by an image. 
I am trying to add a static legend to my map this way.

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of replacing the default attribution, which is not an elegant approach, I would create a new custom control to display my legend. 
What if on next version ol3 change the behaviour of attribution???? You would need to change your code.
Creating a custom control is not that hard. Check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/21nkkr7x/) it is a working example, though it is not perfect as I just wrote it to show you the way and not provide the solution. Good luck, hope to help you